# my rspec test returns similar collection when using contain_exactly matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to run a test where I implemented contain_exactly matcher. My test looks like this:

```
 context 'user with multiple roles' do
      let(:user1) { create(:user, :with_dea, with_roles: ['Physician (MD, DO)', 'Dentist']) }
      let!(:my_rx_request1) { create(:my_rx_request, requestor: user1, dea_numbers: user1.dea_numbers.pluck(:dea_number)) }
      let(:search_params1) {
                            {
                              requestor_first_name: my_rx_request1.requestor.first_name,
                              requestor_last_name: my_rx_request1.requestor.last_name,
                              request_begin_date: DateTime.now - 1.year,
                              request_end_date: DateTime.now + 1.week,
                              dea: my_rx_request1.dea_numbers.first
                            }
                          }
      it 'only shows one result' do
        expect(MyRxHistoryQuery.new(search_params1).exec).to contain_exactly(my_rx_request1)
      end

    end
  end
```

The results for expected collection and actual collection are the same:

```
expected collection contained:  [#<MyRxRequest id: 33, requestor_id: 555, drug_name: nil, dea_numbers: ["XYZ123123"], written_at_begin...at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", updated_at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", npi_numbers: [], request_status: nil>]
       
actual collection contained:    [#<MyRxRequest id: 33, requestor_id: 555, drug_name: nil, dea_numbers: ["XYZ123123"], written_at_begin...at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", updated_at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", npi_numbers: [], request_status: nil>]

the extra elements were:        [#<MyRxRequest id: 33, requestor_id: 555, drug_name: nil, dea_numbers: ["XYZ123123"], written_at_begin...at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", updated_at: "2022-03-17 21:30:12", npi_numbers: [], request_status: nil>]
```

I am not quite sure how to make this test pass. If I use '.to eq[my_rx_request1]' instead of ' contain_exactly' match I get activerecord::relation instead of the class object.

How else I can have this test to pass?

The ' .exec' method looks like this if this helps out pinpoint the issue:

```
def exec
    my_rx_requests = MyRxRequest.joins(user: :roles)
    my_rx_requests.order(order_binds).group(:id) unless search_query.any?
    my_rx_requests.where(sanitized_sql).order(order_binds).group(:id,'users.first_name','users.last_name','roles.title')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: try comparing just the ID

```
expect(MyRxHistoryQuery.new(search_params1).exec
  .map(&:id).to contain_exactly(my_rx_request1.id)
```

> The results for expected collection and actual collection are the
> same:

This is mostly likely false. If you look at the test output, there's a `...` in the middle of the object. This is hiding the attributes that are different in the expected and actual values.

Unfortunately, `contain_exactly` doesn't give useful output when there's a difference between two objects like that. I'd guess that the problem is `requestor: user` in your `create`. That association is present on `my_rx_request1`, but not on the returned object from `exec` (since you didn't load that association in `exec`).

Second possibility: your exec function returns duplicate records due to the join on `users: :roles`, so when you do the comparison by id, you may see something like `expected: [33], actual: [33, 33]`.